# Shapefile with CRS associated to it without the need of a .PRJ?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, prj

I'm new to QGIS and this type of software, but i was wondering if I could make the .shp file (or the .shx) have a CRS associated with them without the need of the .PRJ file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the purpose of your question? Shapefile is a multifile format and always requires more than one files to be valid. So can you explain why you want to get rid of the .PRJ file? Stick e.g. to Geopackage if you want to have a single file for your data.

Comment: You can delete the .prj (and lose the associated CRS). Then when loading into QGIS you can override the missing CRS and assign one temporarily, click the ? next to the layer in the table of contents.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible. The only way Shapefile can have determined CRS is to write it in PRJ file.